# Why does Sass move my @import to the top of the compiled CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

rails 4.1.8, sass-rails 5.0.1, sass 3.4.10, sprockets-rails 2.2.4, sprockets 2.12.3

this is what the top of my application.scss looks like:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= depend_on_asset "myicons.eot"
 *= depend_on_asset "myicons.woff"
 *= depend_on_asset "myicons.ttf"
 *= depend_on_asset "myicons.svg"
 *= depend_on_asset "foo/bar.jpg"
 */

@import "normalize-rails";
@import "bourbon";
@import "grid_settings";
@import "neat";
@import "bitters/base";
```

This is what bitters/base looks like:

```
@import "variables";
@import "extends";
@import "typography";
@import "forms";
@import "tables";
@import "lists";
@import "flashes";
@import "buttons";
```

this is what the top of _typography.scss looks like

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300,500,700);

body {
  color: $base-font-color;
  font-family: $base-font-family;
  font-size: $base-font-size;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  line-height: $base-line-height;
  font-family: $sans-serif;
}
```

And this is what the top of the generated application.css looks like

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*! normalize.css v3.0.1 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300,500,700);
/* line 9, /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/normalize-rails-3.0.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/normalize-rails/normalize.css */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}
```

Problem: note how in the generated css, the two `@import url(...` font lines are injected amongst the normalize.css

What could be causing this? I don't even know where to begin investigating.

Comment: Thanks for the better question title @cimmanon !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import), `@import` rule must be the first rule in the document (except the `@charset` rule).

And Sass likes to produce valid CSS files, so it pushes all `@import`s to the top.

Comment: with some weird/missing rules regarding comments apparently.

Comment: @JohnBachir I read that WordPress themes need to have a comment on top with metadata in order to get that data listed properly. So it will keep the first comment and put `@import` below it